# Reading the contents of a file into a list

Tags: list-manipulation, import, string-manipulation

I would like to read the contents of the [file.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YGaXCKMb0NJdig3-6l40kpcw0JgJSxIP/view?usp=sharing) into a list of the following form: {1,0,1,12,0,1,0.25,0.012,0,1,0.25,0.026,0,1,0.25,0.057,0,1,0.25,0.090}.

How could this be done?

In these variants, the code returns the following {...,Null,...}:

```
ReadList[".../file.txt"]

(*{яю1, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, \
Null, Null, Null, Null}*)

ToExpression[Import[".../file.txt","Words"]]

(*{ÿþ1, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, \
Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, \
Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, \
Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, \
Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, \
Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, \
Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, \
Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null}*)
```

Comment: The link you have is not plain .txt file. It open what seems to be a image or HTML version of the file? Why not put a link to the file itself so one can download it?

Comment: @Nasser, thanks for the commnet! When you click on the [file.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YGaXCKMb0NJdig3-6l40kpcw0JgJSxIP/view?usp=sharing), isn't there a link in the upper right corner that allows you to download the file?

Comment: `Import["https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YGaXCKMb0NJdig3-6l40kpcw0JgJSxIP/view?usp=sharing"]` returns `""`. I don't like to download unknown files. pastebin.com is a way to share files that was recommended to me by users when I joined this site. (Some users won't import encrypted/compressed code, though.)

Comment: At first I did not see there is yet another link on the right top corner of the page. I thought the link itself is where the file is located at. any way, it looks like someone managed to download the file. Hopefully that will work out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
filename = "C:/file.txt";
g = BinaryReadList[filename, "Character16"][[3 ;;]] //
     StringJoin //
    StringReplace[#, {WhitespaceCharacter .. -> " "}] & //
   StringSplit[#, " "] & //
  ToExpression
```

> {1, 0, 1, 12, 0, 1, 0.25, 0.012, 0, 1, 0.25, 0.026, 0, 1, 0.25, 
> 0.057, 0, 1, 0.25, 0.09}

The file has characters `{255,254, ...}` at the beginning that I removed using `Part` after discovering these in the output using `FullForm`.

Answer (score 6):

Your file is saved as UTF-16, so you need to tell Mathematica to use the appropriate encoding:

```
Flatten@Import["file.txt", "Table", CharacterEncoding -> "Unicode"]
(* {1, 0, 1, 12, 0, 1, 0.25, 0.012, 0, 1, 0.25, 0.026, 0, 1, 0.25, 0.057, 0, 1, 0.25, 0.09} *)
```